# GraphQl refetch does not always work on TextField clear value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I am using graphQl to query database records. I created a filter component with materialUi TextField with refetch to run the query after the filter values have been updated.

Sometimes after clearing the values the query is not called once again (e.g. on the date field).

This is my code:

```
const newDate = new Date();
const [date, setDate] = useState(newDate);

const { data, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_ALL, {
        variables: { first: 100, task: task, status: status, week: week, date: date, responsible_entity: responsible, no_incident: no_incident, site: site }, onCompleted: (
        ) => {            setItems(data.getAll)
        }
    });
```

```
<TextField
   id="dateFilter"
   type="date"
   defaultValue={dateToString(myDate)}
   variant="outlined"
   className={classes.textField}
   onChange={(e, v) => { setDate(e.target.value); refetch() }}
/>
```

```
 <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="responsible"

                        render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <Autocomplete
                                id="responsible"
                                options={responsiblesList}
                                defaultValue={{ 'DISTINCT': responsible || '' }}
                                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.DISTINCT}
                                style={{ width: 300 }}
                                className={classes.textField}

                                onInputChange={(event, newInputValue, reason) => {
                                    if (reason === 'clear') {
                                        setResponsible(null)
                                        return
                                    } else {
                                        setResponsible(newInputValue)
                                    }
                                }}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}
                                    label="select responsible"
                                    variant="outlined"

                                    defaultValue={responsible}
                                />}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

Comment: It does not trigger another query refetch when clearing the values...

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to call `refetch()`, since your query is using `date` state.  When you call `setDate(e.target.value)`, your component re-renders, and `useQuery` will be recalled with the updated `date`. Recalling `refetch()` in this case is like doing the same thing two times. Remove it, it may resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot! the problem now is that when I clear the values in the state it sometimes (after the 2nd or 3rd update of the filter), query with the initial values...

Comment: Can you call `setDate("")` after `setResponsible(null)`? I'm not an expert of material ui, but if you can do so it may resolve your problem.

Comment: this is what I am doing. :)

Comment: I’m asking because I’m not seeing you calling `setDate("")` inside this `if (reason === 'clear') {` block.

Comment: well in the second textfield, I am clearing the responsible field. The date field is in the above field (the one without autocomplete...